# can i use java library for java se in java me

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, s60

can i use java library for java se in java me. i use smack java library to create a chat client. can i use the same libary to create a chat client for javame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. 
Java ME uses an old version of the Java language and the java byte code specification, also a lot of the basic standard library functions are not present.
The networking library functions are completely different for instance.
It is very unlikely that a modern Java lib can be used in java ME without serious modifications.

Comment: do you know any xmpp library for java me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no. J2ME uses completely different VM - so it can't use J2SE libraries at all.

Comment: Depending on what the library does, you can extract the original source and perhaps "dumb it down" to allow it to work on J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

No.Can't mingle Java SE & Java ME.So that Java ME has it's own libraries and API's.

Answer (score 0):

You have to port the library in J2ME.